# como resolver el mysql errcode 17

Tags: mysql

como solucionar el mysql error no me permite ver los campos de las tablas necesito ayuda por favor
introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

> error consulta SQL show full fields from dermatologia myql a dicho #1 - can't create/write to file '#sql_2e80_0.MYD' (errcode:17)

Comment: No hay necesidad de usar imágenes, por favor edita y coloca el error como texto; por cierto cuida mas esa pantalla esta a un golpe de caer en pedazos

Comment: Lo lamento; no se ve el error. Transcríbelo como texto, por favor.

Comment: este es el error

Comment: error consulta SQL show full fields from dermatologia myql a dicho #1 - can't create/write to file '#sql_2e80_0.MYD' (errcode:17)